# Horizontal scrolling for Time-Line chart using LineChartView

Tags: ios, ios-charts

I am using `LineChartView` (https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) for Time-Line chart drawing. I am facing following issue. Could anyone help me here?

> 1. How to achieve scrolling in X-direction for long range values instead of making dense line charts.
> 2. How to set minimum Y-Value for the chart? I would like to draw the chart for positive value. It shows Negative value at the bottom.

Comment: I am able to make a solution for my second question, still struggling with my first question. We can achieve it by setting _axisMinimum_ for the axis. In my case, I did set _axisMinimum_ for  **Y-axis**.

`yRightAxis.axisMinimum`